# What determines the completeness of a metric space

Tags: real-analysis

I am considering whether how we choose a metric function that determines the completeness of a metric space,i.e. we can define a metric function that makes $R^n$ not complete, is that true?

Comment: A metric space is a space determined by three conditions, and completeness is determined by the convergence of Cauchy sequence in a metric space.  There are no relation between those terms.

Comment: @NasuSama but u use the metric function to determine the distance between two points of a Cauchy sequence, right?

Comment: Yes, that is right.  You use metric function to check if the sequence is Cauchy, but you can't use the definition of a metric space.  Those are two different ways.

Comment: I think he is asking the question: Does there exist a metric $\rho$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ under which $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is not complete.

Comment: @NasuSama sorry see the edit

Answer (score 1):

The metric does effect completeness. I can't think of an example metric on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ but if you need an example along these lines; The space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$. It is complete under the sup norm (i.e. $d(f,g)=\sup{\{|f(x)-g(x)|}$ ${|x\in{[0,1]}\}}$) but not under the $L_{1}$ norm (i.e. $d(f,g)=\int_{0}^{1}|f-g|$).

Answer (score 0):

There are some technicalities here; the key term is topological completeness. if by $\mathbb R^n$ you're referring to Euclidean n-space, with the standard topology , then , with any equivalent topology $T'$ in $\mathbb R^n$ (As a set of points now) , will also be topologically complete , i.e., there will be an equivalent metric in which $\mathbb R^n , T'$ will be complete. Notice that while $\mathbb R$, standard topology) is homeomorphic to $(0,1), arctanx)$ , and the latter is not complete, there is an equivalent topology where $((0,1), arctanx)$ is complete. Basically, if $(x,d)$ is complete, any space $(Y,d')$  homeomorphic to $(X,d)$ can be made to be complete in the sense that there is a metric $d''$ equivalent to $d'$, such that $(Y,d'')$ is complete. Similar can be said about other properties like metrizability, etc.

Comment: I think he's asking for a metric under which $R^{n}$ is not complete. So the discrete metric won't do the trick, since the only Cauchy sequences are the eventually constant ones.

Comment: @Danul G: you're right; I was thinking of something else; I just edited.